# Is there any stack exchange sites or any other sites which I can ask a subjective question about electronics?

Tags: discussion

I would like to ask a subjective question regarding electronics.

I have read in the [Electronics Stack Exchange FAQ](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/faq) that this sort of question should not be asked.

An example would be (DO NOT POST):

> As an electronics enthusiast or a professional it could be assumed that there are countless components. This eventually leads to a problem on how to store efficiently and safely these components. How do people store their electronic components?

I understand the website FAQ. I would like to ask, is there another stack exchange website where I can ask these sorts of subjective questions or another site for that matter?

I am looking for a suggestion on where I can effectively post these sorts of questions and get reasonable answers.

Comment: Doh, i just realized this question does not satisify the meta faq guidelines. I'll just see how this goes... :| *gulp* help!

Comment: Nah, this question is fine for Meta.  I think that readers will understand it in the context of "Are questions about _____ on or off topic?", which is at the top of the list.

Comment: Subjective questions about electronics work alright in [our EE.SE chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15/electrical-engineering).

Answer (score 4):

It might be worthwhile to have a questions that discusses part storage, as general help and advice. This is a question many people probably have and google, why not allow them a source on our site to help drive traffic and get people involved.

I remembered right off the bat [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/10513/230). Is this what you were looking for? If there is something you can think of that would be a better general fit I think it might be worth discussing what we could put on the site. The above seems like a good reference as normally you will just need to organize parts. However, the question already referencing those bins may have limited the solution space.

Comment: @LeanerRocky, is this what you are looking for. I feel like we have not achieved closure yet.

Answer (score 2):

An excellent site where you can ask virtually any question on electronics related matters is

- [The PICList](http://www.piclist.com/)

This site is ***NOT*** a competitor with or alternative to Stack Exchange. The two are complementary and you would be well served by belonging to both (as I do :-). As can be seen - you can be very active on both systems :-).

A number of other Stack Exchange members are also PICList members. You know who you are.

The PICList uses an email mailing list system with either real time per post emails or a daily digest. There are a limited number of subject categories - far fewer than Stack Exchange, but as a consequence the posts in each category are broader. Main categories are PIC, AVR, Electrical Engineering (note 1), Technology, OT. Have a look. You need to register but there is NO spam at all and you can leave at any time.

Note 1: It's actually "Everything engineering" but you need to join in to see how it works out. EE is anything you can build with your own hand etc, TECHnology is for bigger stuff such as Power Stations.

Comment: @RusselMcMahon, even if you posted a competitor you would be safe. I am a member of a similar exchange for MSP430, I find them very interesting and they are a better home for straight shopping questions as such since they are not intending to be a long term repository and just a simple form of exchange of ideas. I agree they both have their place.